# Displaying the next form below the previous one only once validated

Tags: python, django, forms

I am experienced in Python, but I'm quite new to Django. So I apologize in advance if the answer to my question is quite obvious. That being said, I couldn't figure out how to make the below work after several days.

I have a set of 20 questions which can be either of type:

```
1. forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
2. forms.RadioSelect
3. forms.TextInput
```

What I am aiming for is that as soon as the user submits the answer to the first question, the second question displays just below (the first question turning into read only)... an so on until the user reaches the last question where he gets redirected to a page with the answers.

So far, what I have been able to achieve is to have all questions displayed all thogether with a "Validate" button at the bottom (redirecting to the answer page).

I would gratefully accept any lead or piece of advice.

**EDIT 17/11/2019**: I'm wondering if that can be achieved using **Formset**. Does it make sense?

Thanks.
Eric